modelsim can't find object (vish-4014) and i it doesn't show any wave so that can i add it to scope
this is my code for a fun Fire extinguishing system in a 50 unit apartment.this is fire_detection_system.v:
module fire_detection_system (
    input wire clk, // Clock signal
    input wire reset, // Reset signal
    input wire [49:0] smoke_detectors, // Smoke sensor signal
    input wire [4:0] floor_buttons, // Buttons on each floor
    input wire janitor_button, // Janitor button
    output wire [49:0] sprinkler_activate // Sprinkler activation signal
);
    reg [5:0] timer; // 6-bit timer for 60-second delay
    reg [1:0] state; // State machine: 00 (idle), 01 (waiting), 10 (active)
    
    assign sprinkler_activate = (state == 2'b10) ? smoke_detectors : 50'b0;  // Activate sprinklers in active state
    always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
        if (reset) begin
            timer <= 0;
            state <= 2'b00; // Initialize to idle state
        end else begin
            case (state)
                2'b00: // Idle state
                    if (smoke_detectors != 50'b0) begin
                        state <= 2'b01; // Transition to waiting state
                        timer <= 60; // Set timer to 60 seconds
                    end
                2'b01: // Waiting state
                    if (timer > 0) begin // Decrement timer
                        timer <= timer - 1;
                    end else begin
                        state <= 2'b10; // Transition to active state
                    end
                2'b10: // Active state
                    if (floor_buttons != 5'b0 || janitor_button) begin
                        state <= 2'b00; // Reset to idle state on button press
                    end
            endcase
        end
    end

endmodule

and this is my fire_detection_system_tb.v:
module fire_detection_system_tb;

  // Inputs
  reg clk;
  reg reset;
  reg [49:0] smoke_detectors;
  reg [4:0] floor_buttons;
  reg janitor_button;

  // Outputs
  wire [49:0] sprinkler_activate;

  // Instantiate the fire detection system
  fire_detection_system dut (
    .clk(clk),
    .reset(reset),
    .smoke_detectors(smoke_detectors),
    .floor_buttons(floor_buttons),
    .janitor_button(janitor_button),
    .sprinkler_activate(sprinkler_activate)
  );

  // Clock generation
  always begin
    #5 clk = ~clk;
  end

  initial begin
    // Initialize inputs
    clk = 0;
    reset = 1;
    smoke_detectors = 50'b0;
    floor_buttons = 5'b0;
    janitor_button = 0;

    #10;  // Wait for reset to settle

    // Test cases
    smoke_detectors = 50'b0;
    floor_buttons = 5'b0;
    janitor_button = 0;
    #60;  // Wait for timer to expire

    smoke_detectors = 50'b1;
    floor_buttons = 5'b0;
    janitor_button = 0;
    #60;  // Wait for timer to expire and sprinklers to activate

    smoke_detectors = 50'b1;
    floor_buttons = 5'b1;
    janitor_button = 0;
    #1;  // Wait for button press to be detected

    smoke_detectors = 50'b0;
    floor_buttons = 0;
    janitor_button = 1;
    #60;  // Wait for timer to expire and sprinklers to deactivate

    $finish;
  end

endmodule


i want to show the signal that i have been used inside initial box on modelsim scope, but modelsim doesn't recognize any wave signal in this file. and the files have been compilled correctly without errors.simulation layout

In the attached picture of your simulation layout you do not have the Objects window open which will show all of the signals available in the module selected in the Instance window. Open the Objects window by going to View on the menu bar and select Objects. Once the Object window is open make sure your testbench is selected in the Instance window, and then you will see the signals from your initial block in the Object window.

